# How to write a research proposal where the project description is given and known?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-proposal

I am applying for this PhD studentship, where the project is known and is about a specific procedure. I have seen [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77822/how-to-write-a-research-proposal-for-a-phd-position-where-the-description-of-the) question, here the chap who answers the question mentions to look at the description like a job advert and to look at the research proposal as a cover letter, so probably covering why you would be suitable for that position.

However, the position I am applying for, is a group/Lab within department department X, and department X mentions the following about a research proposal for their graduate roles:

> Your proposal should focus on research rather than personal achievements, interests and aspirations.

It's also worth mentioning that it has a world limit of 500, so not that long. It also mentions that the proposal will be assessed based on:

- the coherence of the proposal
- the originality of the project
- an understanding of the proposed area of study
- the feasibility of successfully completing the project in the time available (a maximum of 4 years)
- knowledge of research techniques and suitability to undertake the proposed work

I have also tried to contact the supervisor, he mentioned that he would try to connect soon, but then he never came back, the deadline is also in a few days, so I don't have any other options. Not surprisingly, the department also mentions that it is expected for students to talk to potential supervisors about the proposal.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What country and what field are you in?

Comment: @astronat I'm in the UK, and this is going to be in bioelectronics/neuroscience

Comment: I'm in the UK in bioscience. I generally advise applicants just to write that you are applying for an advertised project and provide a link in that box. To be honest, the only person that sees the form is me anyway. However, I'm loath to suggest that here without confirmation from someone at the intuition in question. Have you tried contacting the graduate admissions tutor or secretary at the department?